# Use google smart home action for hotels and restricting access of rooms per device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-smart-home

We are using Google home in hotels and we have a smart home skill. The problem with Hotel we are facing is, in sync response to google smat home action, we are sending all devices of all rooms of hotels, but we want to restrict access to only one room of hotel for that device(Google Home Mini/Nest Hub). How can I do that ?
Is it possible with Alexa ?

Comment: Use the "contact us" link at https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-for-hospitality to ask this of an Alexa rep.

Comment: We are from India and Sadly Alexa For Hospitality is currently not available in India currently

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your devices aren’t differentiated correctly during implementation as a single query is returning all the list of devices that are connected. Furthermore, if you want to have separate SYNC responses for every room, then you can try to create a new account for each room (Google’s documentation for correctly implementing the [SYNC intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/intents#sync)).

If you want information on how to set up devices for hotel rooms, visit https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access